# SQL Server: how to disable several Logins simultaneously via Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have several User logins (SQL Server and Windows) in SQL Server and have to disable them.

To disable 1 Login I would use

```
ALTER LOGIN [AD\001] DISABLE
```

Manually using properties / settings would take a long time. What does the script look like to disable several logins?

And can I use WHERE and LIKE, for example, because most logins begin with "AD ".

e.g.

```
ALTER LOGIN DISABLE
WHERE Login LIKE "%AD\"
```

Comment: There is no way around issuing multiple `ALTER LOGIN` instructions, one after another. You can query the DMVs to extract the logins and build a dynamic SQL to pass to `EXEC` as an alternative.

Comment: Loop through logins to be disabled and buid execute ALTER command.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to dynamically build a script that will do that.**

```sql
SELECT N'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(sp.name) + N' DISABLE;'
FROM sys.server_principals sp
WHERE sp.type IN ('S','U','G','E','X')
 AND sp.name LIKE LIKE N'%AD\';
```

`'S','U','G','E','X'` represent different login types, [see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

To programmatically execute that, you can use `STRING_AGG` and `EXEC`:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(
     CAST(N'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(sp.name) + N' DISABLE;' AS nvarchar(max)), N'
')
  FROM sys.server_principals sp
  WHERE sp.type IN ('S','U','G','E','X')
   AND sp.name LIKE LIKE N'%AD\'
);

EXEC (@sql);
```